# calling and executing a file in php

Tags: php

this might sound weird :)

i want to "call" a file( test_2.php ) i.e execute the file like how it would have been when clicking on the following link:

```
<a href="home/test_2.php">click here</a>  //this code is currently in test_1.php file
```

is there any method to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you mean is, when you click the link, you want that php to get executed, but you don't want the page to change/reload.

Ajax is your friend here. If you are using jquery, just one line of javascript code will do it:

```
$.get('home/test_2.php', function(data, txt){ alert(txt); });
```

read more about this function at [jQuery.get documentation.](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get)

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Are you possibly looking for include()?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 1):

I think [Curl](https://www.php.net/curl) is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may want include()?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

```
<?php
  include("test2.php"); //This is just like inserting test2.php's code in this file
  /* rest of the code */
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding your answer, especially the link part, but do you perhaps mean including files http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php?

Answer (score 0):

If your server supports it, include() using a `http://` URL should do the trick and produce exactly the desired result.

If you include a filesystem path (e.g. `include /home/sites/www.example.com/test.php`) the file would be `parsed` in the current context which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean run a script and catch it's output? For that I use the following:

```
    /**
    *       Execute a php file and return it's output.
    *       The file will be executed in the script's context. 
    *       It is not sandboxed in any way and it can access the global scope.
    *
    *       @param  string  $file           The file to execute.
    *       @param  array   &$context       An optional array of name=>value 
    *                       pairs to define additional context.
    *       @return string  The file's output.
    */
    function execFile($file, &$context=NULL)
    {
            if(is_array($context)) 
            {
                    extract($context, EXTR_SKIP);
            }

            ob_start();
            include $file;
            $ret = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            return $ret;
    }
```

Be careful what you give to this function.